# hide and show variable white ajax jquery

Tags: html, css, ajax

Hi guys i have a problem in this code i want to show variable in content
look in this code

i want to show variable $name in div #divToToggle after click but the varible not working normal text he's working normally but variable no

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleAndChangeText() {
         $('#divToToggle').toggle();
         if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
              $('#aTag').html('Collapsed text mode &#9658');
         }
         else {
              $('#aTag').html('Expanded text mode &#9660');
         }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
       $name = 'sasdsad'; 
    ?>
    <div>
    <a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleAndChangeText();">
       Expanded text mode &#9660;
    </a>
    <div id="divToToggle">
       <?php echo $name; ?>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/8rcgf5pw/

Comment: thanks so much Mr Kishan 
can you see this another problem please 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228406/hide-and-show-content-in-loop-php-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.)you run you code in xampp server because it's a php code.
2.)save file with .php extension.
```

if you use html then use [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agfjbw7n/)

Comment: No i run my code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i want to use variable not text normaly

Comment: ah oki thanks its worked i save my file in php

Comment: but i have last answer plz how can hide #divToToggle content in page after click in Expanded text mode

Comment: please i need your help how can hide content in page before click i dont show the content before click

Comment: keep it hidden by using css at start