# hide and show content in loop php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdo

Hi guys i need some help i have these code i need to show content by id
after clik to show content i need to show content by the same id

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleAndChangeText() {
         $('#divToToggle').toggle();
         if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
              $('#aTag').html('Collapsed text mode &#9658');
         }
         else {
              $('#aTag').html('Expanded text mode &#9660');
         }
    }
 </script>

 <style>
 #divToToggle{display:none;}
 </style>
```

and this code php/html

```
          <?php 
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `topic` ORDER BY id");
        $stmt->execute();   
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
        echo" 
        <div class='Post'>
        <div class='rgt Pimg'><a href='post.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='".$row['e_title']."' class='Pimg'/></a></div>
        <div>
        <a id='aTag' href='javascript:toggleAndChangeText()'>
           Show Content
        </a>
        <div id='divToToggle'>".$row['e_content']."</div>
        </div>
        ";
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: First of all, please describe more clearly what the current status is and what you need help with. Dumping your code and asking people to finish your project is not the way to go. Also, `id`s should be unique. In your code that is certainly not the case, and that might be an important part of the issue.

Comment: Hello Mr GolezTrol -  honestly I do not have much experience in Jquery hat's why I ask you here help me how can be modified id in code Jquery that's what i need please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use same `ID`'s for multiple elements. Use `class` instead:

Change your script to :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.aTag").on("click", function(){
       var toggleElement = $(this).closest("div").find(".divToToggle");
       toggleElement.toggle();
         if (toggleElement.css('display') == 'none') {
              $(this).html('Collapsed text mode &#9658');
         }
         else {
              $(this).html('Expanded text mode &#9660');
         }
    }); 

 });
```

And your PHP code to this:

```
 <?php 
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `topic` ORDER BY id");
    $stmt->execute();   
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo" 
    <div class='Post'>
    <div class='rgt Pimg'><a href='post.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='".$row['e_title']."' class='Pimg'/></a></div>
    <div>
    <a class='aTag' href='javascript:toggleAndChangeText()'> 
       Show Content
    </a>
    <div class='divToToggle'>".$row['e_content']."</div>
    </div>
    ";
    }
  ?>
```